# Using Substring/CharIndex

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, substring

I've got to extract text from an 'unclean' field in our database. Does anybody know how to extract only: **'daily usage too high'** from the below examples?

```
Order: T001.1<br />Rejection Reason: Meter Read Rejected: daily usage too high<br /><br /><a href='http://********?ProfileId=111111&AccountId=22222&ProductId=11111&MeterId=11111'>Link to page</a>
```

Another example:

```
<b>Order: </b>Notification<br /><b>Rejection Reason: </b>Meter Read Rejected: daily usage too high<br /><br /><br /><a href='http://********ProfileId=11111&AccountId=11111&ContractId=1111&WaterId=2222&MeterId=22222&MOT=true'>Meter page</a>
```

Comment: I'm using SSMS by Microsoft

Comment: Why are you storing HTML instead of meaningful/useful data?

Comment: Read what you wrote and then see if you understand it without knowing anything about your system, your data, your goal. You mentioned looking for particular string. That's simple enough. Then you add a second example without that string. Focus on your goal first. What EXACTLY do you want to do with the string you have provided using tsql? You want to write logic for a where clause? You want to  parse and return some portion of the string? Do you think you might need to include Order # somehow? Does this string have a **reliable** pattern? And do you know that or assume it?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to find the value between 3rd occurrence of `:` and `<br>`

If so,you can use `Stuff` with `cross apply`. Here `cross apply` is needed to find the 3rd occurance of `:`

```
SELECT 
SUBSTRING(STUFF(texi, 1, CHARINDEX(':',texi,P3.pos), ''), 0, 
          CHARINDEX('<', STUFF(texi, 1, CHARINDEX(':',texi,P3.pos), ''))) as mystring
from test
cross apply (select (CHARINDEX(':',texi))) as P1(Pos)
cross apply (select (CHARINDEX(':',texi, P1.Pos+1))) as P2(Pos)
cross apply (select (CHARINDEX(':',texi, P2.Pos+1))) as P3(Pos)
```

[**CHECK DEMO HERE**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f0fe3265267ca48b0f2472677415af85)

Answer (score 0):

You can look for the string `'Meter Read Rejected'` and take the value after that:

```
select left(v.str, patindex('%[^0-9a-zA-Z ]%', v.str) - 1)
from (values ('Order: T001.1<br />Rejection Reason: Meter Read Rejected: daily usage too high<br /><br /><a href=''http://********?ProfileId=111111&AccountId=22222&ProductId=11111&MeterId=11111''>Link to page</a>'),
             ('<b>Order: </b>Notification<br /><b>Rejection Reason: </b>Meter Read Rejected: daily usage too high<br /><br /><br /><a href=''http://********ProfileId=11111&AccountId=11111&ContractId=1111&WaterId=2222&MeterId=22222&MOT=true''>Meter page</a>')
     ) s(str) cross apply
     (values (stuff(s.str, 1, charindex('Meter Read Rejected: ', s.str) + 20, ''))) v(str)
```